# Is an operating system kernel an interpeter for all other programs?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, kernel

So, from my understanding, there are two types of programs, those that are interpreted and those that are compiled. Interpreted programs are executed by an interpreter that is a native application for the platform its on, and compiled programs are themselves native applications (or system software) for the platform they are on.

But my question is this: is anything besides the kernel actually being  directly run by the CPU? A Windows Executable is a "Windows Executable", not an x86 or amd64 executable. Does that mean every other process that's not the kernel is literally being interpreted by the kernel in the same way that a browser interprets Javascript? Or is the kernel placing these processes on the "bare metal" that the kernel sits on top of?

IF they're on the "bare metal", how, say does Windows know that a program is a windows program and not a Linux program, since they're both compiled for amd64 processors? If it's because of the "format" of the executable, how is that executable able to run on the "bare metal", since, to me, the fact that it's formatted to run on a particular OS would mean that some interpretation would be required for it to run.

Is this question too complicated for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They run on the "bare metal", but they do contain operating system-specific things. An executable file will typically provide some instructions to the kernel (which are, arguably, "interpreted") as to how the program should be loaded into memory, and the file's code will provide ways for it to "hook" in to the running operating system, such as by an operating system's API or via device drivers. Once such a non-interpreted program is loaded into memory, it runs on the bare metal but continues to communicate with the operating system, which is also running on the bare metal.

In the days of single-process operating systems, it was common for executables to essentially "seize" control of the entire computer and communicate with hardware directly. Computers like the Apple ][ and the Commodore 64 work like that. In a modern multitasking operating system like Windows or Linux, applications and the operating system share use of the CPU via a complex multitasking arrangement, and applications access the hardware via a set of abstractions built in to the operating system's API and its device drivers. Take a course in Operating System design if you are interested in learning lots of details.

Bouncing off Junaid's answer, the way that the kernel blocks a program from doing something "funny" is by controlling the allocation and usage of memory. The kernel requires that memory be requested and accessed through it via its API, and thus protects the computer from "unauthorized" access. In the days of single-process operating systems, applications had much more freedom to access memory and other things directly, without involving the operating system. An application running on an old Apple ][ can read to or write to any address in RAM that it wants to on the entire computer.

One of the reasons why a compiled application won't just "run" on another operating system is that these "hooks" are different for different operating systems. For example, an application that knows how to request the allocation of RAM from Windows might not have any idea how to request it from Linux or the Mac OS. As Disk Crasher mentioned, these low level access instructions are inserted by the compiler.

Comment: OK... I guess my confusion is how can a process that is running directly by the CPU contain instructions to "hook" on to an OS API or driver since the CPU instruction set obviously isn't going to have specific instructions for every single OS or driver written for it. I'm sure the real answers to these questions are super technical and would require taking a class. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You're very welcome. Yes, the ways in which applications "hook" into the operating system is rather technical and a class would probably be the best way to learn the details.

Comment: @RyanW Because the compiler figures out what OS calls must be made and generates low-level code accordingly.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Any memory location except ROM memory, that is.

Comment: @DiskCrasher of course. I thought about mentioning that but decided that it was implicit that I was talking about RAM. I updated my answer to be more explicit. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertColumbia and DiskCrasher Thanks for your continued clarification. It never really occurred to me that machine level instructions could be written to express interactions for specific OSes. I just assumed that any instruction meant to be received by a kernel would need to literally be run "on top" of the kernel. It makes sense that, with the right compiler, machine code could be made for the task. I won't ask how it works specifically because at some point the answer is "read the gcc source code" ;). I feel like I have a rough understanding of the general concept now though so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing things. A compiled program is in machine readable format. When you run the program, kernel will allocate memory, cpu etc and ensure that the program does not interfere with other programs. If the program requires access to HW resources or disk etc, the kernel will handle it so kernel will always be between hardware and any software you run in user space.

If the program is interpreted, then a relevant interpreter for that language will convert the code to machine readable on the fly and kernel will still provide the same functionality like access to hardware and making sure programs aren't doing anything funny like trying to access other program memory etc.

Comment: Right. I guess my confusion is how can "machine readable" code be tailored for an OS since the machine instruction set can't possibly have instructions for every possible OS written for it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hopefully i don't confuse you more but i think you need to understand a build process for programs also includes a stage called Link. The way i understand it, a linker will look at all the different source files, dependencies etc and link all these things together to create the final object file. Now there may be libraries or functions available in Linux but no windows (windows mainly has dll files). So the object file won't run on the other platform. Different CPU models also require separately compiled programs.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that runs on "bare metal" is [assembly language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) code, which is abstracted from the programmer by many layers in the OS and compiler. Generally speaking, applications are compiled to an OS and CPU architecture. They will not run on other OS's, at least not without a compatible framework in place (e.g. [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) on Linux).

Back in the day a lot of code used to be written on bare metal using [macro assemblers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler), but that's pretty much unheard of on PCs today. (And there was even a time before macro assemblers.)